# How to make org-agenda time-grid :LOGBOOK: entries appear in the same format as entries logged with CLOSED:

Tags: org-agenda

I recently made the following modification to my init.el to show :LOGBOOK: entries in the org-agenda time-grid:

```
(use-package org
  (setq org-agenda-log-mode-items '(closed clock state)))
```

The only problem is that the entries for these :LOGBOOK: items are in a different format than the rest of the closed tasks in the time-grid.

NORMAL : `Closed: 12:30-13:45 routine: DONE Eat lunch`

LOGBOOK: `State: (CLOSED) 12:30-13:45 routine: DONE Eat lunch`

How can I fix it so that the `(CLOSED)` bit doesn't get added, or perhaps moved to a place where it doesn't affect the alignment of the timestamps?

I've tried the following:

- I tried messing with `org-agenda-prefix-format`.
- I tried searching for help pages for any variable or function named `*agenda*log*`, and none of the ones I found applied to this.

Comment: The formats are hardwired. You'd have to change the [code](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/org-agenda.el#n6126).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @NickD for telling me where to find it. Indeed the solution is to change the definition of `(org-agenda-get-progress)`. The part to be changed is about 20 lines up from the end of the function.

This has been edited after @NickD pointed out that the original was a bad solution. Hope this works better.

Change the following:

```
...
(setq txt (org-agenda-format-item
           (cond
            (closedp "Closed:   ")
            (statep (concat "State:     (" state ")"))
            (t (concat "Clocked:   (" clocked ")")))
...
```

To this:

```
...
(setq txt (org-agenda-format-item
           (cond
            (closedp (concat "Closed:       " (spaces-string 12))
            (statep (concat "State:      (" state ")" (spaces-string (- 12 (length state)))))
            (t (concat "Clocked:    (" clocked ")" (spaces-string (- 12 (length clocked))))))
...
```

The number 12 in `(spaces-string 12)` and `(spaces-string (- 12 (length state)))` can be whatever you want it to be, and maybe there's a way to calculate the "correct" value without hard-coding it, but it works for me. It's just for alignment. Also on the subject of alignment:

Make sure to modify `org-agenda-prefix-format` to make the rest of the time-grid entries align properly based on the number of spaces added to the ones above. I calculated it needs 14 extra spaces, but it might be different for others.

Comment: I think the resulting output would be misleading: you'd get `State: 12:30-13:45 routine: DONE Eat lunch` without *any* indication of what state the item is in. I would not recommend that you do it this way.

Comment: You are right, I'm working on something a little better which retains both the extra information and the alignment.

Comment: If you fork the code, you should also think carefully about how to maintain your changes in the long run; otherwise, you'll be chasing your tail every time you upgrade Org (whether you do the upgrade yourself or whether your distro does it for you) - DAMHIKT...

Comment: Any advice on what would be a good way to maintain it? I have never forked/maintained a project before but I'm eager to learn.

Comment: Yes: don't if you can avoid it. Either figure out a *good* way to do what you want and submit it as a suggested change (see [How to contribute](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contribute.html)) - if it is accepted, you are home free. If not, maybe you decide that you can live with the code as is, despite the formatting problem. If neither of these is palatable to you, then it depends on how you do your upgrades. The trouble is that the question is off-topic for this site;also this is a wide and open-ended question which doesn't really work for *any* SE site. Maybe reddit is the best place to ask.

Comment: I did a Google search for "how to maintain a fork of a project" and it came up with lots of answers, but most of them AFAICT are specific to git (or even more specific to GitHub). But it may be a starting place for you.